# Navigation from a stack screen to tab navigator with reset does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

I have login screen and main screen. My main screen has `Tab.Navigator`. When i click on login button of login screen i want to navigate to main screen and remove all the previous routes which are present in stack. When i use `navigation.navigate` it works but it does not remove previous route but when i use `navigation.reset` it navigates to a white screen with none of my tabs visible

Here is my code

In `App.tsx`

```
<NavigationContainer>
     <StatusBar
       barStyle={isDarkMode ? 'light-content' : 'dark-content'}
       backgroundColor={backgroundStyle.backgroundColor}
     />
     <Stack.Navigator>
       <Stack.Screen
         name={LoginRoute}
         component={Login}
         options={{headerShown: false}}
       />
       <Stack.Screen
         name={MainRoute}
         component={Main}
         options={{headerShown: false}}
       />
     </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>
```

In `Main` component

```
const Main = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={({route}) => ({
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: {backgroundColor: greenColor, height: 90},
        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
          return <MainItem routeName={route.name} focused={focused} />;
        },
        tabBarLabel: () => <></>,
      })}>
      <Tab.Screen name={home} component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name={discover} component={DiscoverScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name={explore} component={ExploreScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name={manage} component={ManageScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name={profile} component={ProfileScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

In login screen's login button press i have added following code

```
navigation.reset({
          index: 0,
          routes: [{name: MainRoute}],
        });
```

but i get white screen when i do this. How to navigate to main screen and remove previous routes as well